# Load NSARRAY from NSCOREDATA

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have save a NSARRAY in my nscoredatabase in binarydata type attribute saved with this code

```
AppDelegate *AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[AppDelegate managedObjectContext];

//guardar array
NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:roll];


    NSManagedObject *newContact;

newContact = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Horarios"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];

   [newContact setValue:arrayData forKey:@"valor"];


    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
```

But i dont know how to get it back from the data store to work again with this NSARRAY

Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean `load it again`? You mean how to get the new object back out of the data store?

Comment: exactly, get from the data store

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetching.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Horarios"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *matches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: i get this: 

 "<NSManagedObject: 0x1a22d940> (entity: Horarios; id: 0x9f33eb0 <x-coredata://22528E96-027F-4328-B259-105F41D90715/Horarios/p1> ; data: <fault>)"

i think i need to make some more to convert to normal array

Comment: what is your `NSLog` statement? can you please post it? or post more in general? otherwise it's difficult to help you!

Comment: My NSLOG of *matches array is:

"<NSManagedObject: 0x113514b0> (entity: Horarios; id: 0x11350a50 <x-coredata://22528E96-027F-4328-B259-105F41D90715/Horarios/p1> ; data: <fault>)",

Comment: AppDelegate *AppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [AppDelegate managedObjectContext];
   
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Horarios"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
    
    
    
    NSLog(@"%@", matches);

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding this line

```
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```